# How to push new version from Firebase to Google Play Console

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

I have a CI/CD which is publishing release AAB to Firebase. It is distributed for QA from there.

Also I have linked my app in Firebase with my app in Google Play Console like this:

[image]

When I click on Distribute an AAB - I get to App Distribution and see no way to push new version to Play Console.

On the Play Console it does not seem to appear in the list of available artifacts, at least for several hours.

So the question is:

Should I somehow push AAB from Firebase Distribution to Google Play Console, or it will happen automatically, if they are linked, or the only option is to upload new AAB to Google Play Console manually.